# php-resque job perform function not executed?

Tags: php, redis, php-resque

I'm trying to make a background job with php-resque. I have this code:

```
\Resque::setBackend('127.0.0.1:6379');
\Resque::enqueue('default', '\BaseModule\Jobs\Mail',  array());
```

and in Mail class i have this

```
class Mail
{

   public function perform()
    {
            lakdf;  
    }
}
```

The mistake on "lakdf;" is here on purpose.

When I turn on monitor on my redis and try to execute job it write this:

```
1387283121.312817 [0 127.0.0.1:32827] "set" "resque:worker:michal-pc:9622:default" "{\"queue\":\"default\",\"run_at\":\"Tue Dec 17 12:25:21 UTC 2013\",\"payload\":{\"class\":\"\\\\BaseModule\\\\Jobs\\\\Mail\",\"args\":[[]],\"id\":\"c7c64e218bc951018c2a264eaf5a4b9a\"}}"
1387283121.313312 [0 127.0.0.1:32827] "incrby" "resque:stat:processed" "1"
```

So from the "reque:stat:processed" I think, that my job was processed, but there is a mistake in perform function and its not writing any error, like the perform function is never executed.

Even if I make some insert to database in perform function it will do nothing.

Does anybody know, where is problem? Why it seems that perform function is not executed?

Comment: What version of PHPResque are you using?

Comment: I have good fealeeng that your PHP function not support this or module missing. Give us your version please.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will assume that

```
    lakdf;
```

is:

```
$lakdf;
```

So if you really want an error to be thrown then you can force one by replacing that line with:

```
error_log("I am throwing an error from within the Mail::perform function");
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope that will help in just single command:

```
$command = 'php ' . 'background_process_autoresponder.php';
$a = shell_exec(sprintf('%s > /dev/null 2>&1 &', $command));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16031606)

Comment: I have just register over stack flow , but my work exp is over 6 years hopefully soon i increase my reputation , Thanks for your review